# how to get the actual position of a motion event for a system overlay button

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

When showing an application overlay button in android via display over other apps permission, I set a motion event listener to allow the user to drag the button around onscreen, but the position that I get from event.rawY isn't atually accurate and appears to have the status bars and maybe navigation bars subtracted from the resulting y position.

As a result the button is always below where the user is actually touching by approx 80 dp even though I have calcuated in the buttons height, and the width is spot on

```
val displayMetrics = displayData.getInstance()
cursorView = Button(context)
val cursorSize = displayMetrics.screenSizeX / 10
cursorView?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cursor)
cursorParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    cursorSize, cursorSize,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
)
cursorParams?.gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.TOP

cursorParams?.x = (displayMetrics.screenSizeX - cursorSize) / 2
cursorParams?.y = (displayMetrics.screenSizeY - cursorSize) / 2

cursorView?.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            cursorParams?.x = (event.rawX - cursorSize / 2).toInt()
            cursorParams?.y = (event.rawY - cursorSize / 2).toInt()
            Tools.logMessage(message ="Screen Size: ${displayMetrics.screenSizeX} x ${displayMetrics.screenSizeY}")
            Tools.logMessage(message ="Calculated Cursor Position: ${cursorParams?.x}, ${cursorParams?.y}")

            windowManager.updateViewLayout(cursorView, cursorParams)
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}

windowManager.addView(cursorView, cursorParams)
```

is there a better way of getting the actual movement position relative to the actual screen size, besides calculating the height of the status and navigation bars?
the displayData class is where I have the actual screen size stored, and it is accurate, which I have confimed

Comment: Please pist the xml that contains such a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out, as I suspected the coordinates returned from the motion event were relative to the screen minus the staus and navigation bars, passing in FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN flag to the window manager resolves that and gives the actual event position

```
    cursorView = Button(context)
    cursorSize = displayMetrics.screenSizeX / 10
    cursorView?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.target)
    cursorParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            cursorSize, cursorSize,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN, // Add this flag
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    )

    cursorParams?.gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.TOP


    cursorParams?.x = (displayMetrics.screenSizeX - cursorSize) / 2
    cursorParams?.y = (displayMetrics.screenSizeY - cursorSize) / 2


    cursorView?.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                cursorParams?.x = (event.rawX - cursorSize / 2).toInt()
                cursorParams?.y = (event.rawY - cursorSize / 2).toInt()
                Tools.logMessage(message ="Screen Size: ${displayMetrics.screenSizeX} x ${displayMetrics.screenSizeY}")
                Tools.logMessage(message ="Calculated Cursor Position: ${cursorParams?.x}, ${cursorParams?.y}")

                windowManager.updateViewLayout(cursorView, cursorParams)
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
```